# No logged in user in Authenticate middleware but in other Middlewares

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

**Introduction**
My problem is, that I have no logged in user when trying to use the `auth` middleware to restrict a route to logged in users but I do have one when getting redirected back to the login page.

**Details**
Let's just assume I have only these two routes

*Route with web middleware*

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'web'], function($router) {
    /** @var Registrar $router */
    $router->get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
});
```

*Route with auth middleware*

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    $router->get('/listings', ['as' => 'listings', 'uses' => 'ListingController@index']);
});
```

The first route works without problems, the second route however redirects me back to the login page. This should only be done, when I have no logged in user, but I logged in before! Which is weird.

When I add these two lines of code to the `handle` function of the `Middleware` `Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` which is used in the `web` group

```
$user = \Auth::user();
dd($user);
```

I'm getting a dump of a the currently logged in user object. However, when adding those lines in the `FeedParser\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` Middleware I'm getting `null` as a dump. How can it be, that the user is logged in in the one middleware, but not in the other? What do I need to do to make it work again? Or better: What more information would you need to help me solve the problems

**Updates**
*If someone asks for more information or more code I will post it here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this happened after upgrading to 5.2?

I believe the route should include both the `web` and the `auth` middleware, such as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('home');
});
```

Comment: Thank you...Yeah, it happened after upgrading in 5.2 and I'm also not using the routes.php for creating routes but classes. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. You may find it useful to create a new middleware group that joins 'web' and 'auth' if you use them a lot together.

Comment: Goodluck and Cool! :) Not sure why it's not "outta the box"

Comment: Hm, in the routes.php you have the following lines of code `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();` so maybe because it's done automatically and only not working because I'm using a different approach for routing? Not sure though